# Getting max value out of a dataframe column of timestamp in scala/spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working with a spark dataframe where it contains the entire timestamp values from the `Column` 'IMG_CREATED_DT'.I have used `collectAsList()` and `toString()` method to get the values as `List` and converting in to `String`. But I am not getting how to fetch the max value out of it.Please guide me on this.

```
 val query_new =s"""(select IMG_CREATED_DT from 
 ${conf.get(UNCAppConstants.DB2_SCHEMA)}.$table)"""

 println(query_new)

 val db2_op=ConnectionUtilities_v.createDataFrame(src_props,srcConfig.url,query_new)

val t3 = db2_op.select("IMG_CREATED_DT").collectAsList().toString
```

How to get the max value out of `t3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the max value form dataframe itself. Try the following sample.

```
val t3 = db2_op.agg(max("IMG_CREATED_DT").as("maxVal")).take(1)(0).get(0)
```

Comment: When I do this, I get a result of type `Any` instead of `java.sql.Timestamp` - Also `maxVal` seemingly is useless

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the max timestamp, use

```
val t3 = db2_op.agg(max("IMG_CREATED_DT")).take(1)(0).getAs[java.sql.Timestamp](0)
```

or

```
val t3 = db2_op.agg(max("IMG_CREATED_DT")).head().getAs[java.sql.Timestamp](0)
```

will return a value that is `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Failing to use `.getAs[T]` will result in the data needing to be inferred which could return type = `Any` rather than type = `T`.